# VueJS2 Accessing HTML Elements within Child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am usually using the `ref` keyword to access components within vue. But I seem to not have understood how I access HTML tags from within a component.

I tried:

```
<input type="text" ref="searchAddress" id="searchAddress" name="searchAddress" class="form-control" v-model="incidentForm.searchAddress">
```

and within the vue component:

```
var input = this.$refs.searchAddress;
```

but this does not work, so I assume it only works when referencing components? How do I access the input tag from within vue?

I created a class for managing all the GoogleMaps Api calls that will be included into my Vue files. Therefore I do not see a way, how I could handle accessing the data of a specific input field. What would be the right approach to avoid a direct access like this?

The full code example and being more specific:
The Autocomplete Function of GoogleMaps does not return anything as I would expect. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'autocompletePlace' of undefined`. `this.autocompletePlace = place` seems to be not working.

```
methods: {
        initMap: function initMap() {
            this.initialLocation = this.createInitialLocation(48.184845, 11.252553);
            this.mapSetup(this.$refs.map, this.initialLocation, function () {
                this.initAutoCompleteListener(function (place) {
                    this.autocompletePlace = place;
                });
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
```

**GoogleMapsApi.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            map: '',
            currentIncidentLocation: '',
            autocomplete: '',
            searchMarker: ''
        }
    },

    events: {
        currentIncidentLocation: function(location) {
            this.currentIncidentLocation = location;
        }
    },

    methods: {
        createInitialLocation: function(latitude, longitude) {
            return new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        },

        mapSetup: function(selector, initialLocation, callback) {
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(selector, {
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            });
            this.map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            this.searchMarker = this.createMarker();
            var input = document.getElementById('searchAddress');
            this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            callback();
        },

        initAutoCompleteListener: function(callback) {
            this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    window.alert("Der Ort konnte nicht gefunden werden");
                    return;
                }
                callback(place);
            }.bind(this));
        },

        createMarker: function() {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: this.map
            })
            return marker;
        }
    }
}
```

**GISView.vue**

```
<template>
    <div ref="map" id="map" class="google-map" style="height: 800px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import GoogleMaps from '../mixins/GoogleMaps.js';

    export default {
        mixins: [GoogleMaps],

        data() {
            return {
                initialLocation: '',
                autocompletePlace: ''
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.$events.$on("MapsAPILoaded", eventData => this.initMap());
        },

        methods: {
            initMap: function() {
                this.initialLocation = this.createInitialLocation(48.184845, 11.252553);
                this.mapSetup(this.$refs.map, this.initialLocation, function() {
                    this.initAutoCompleteListener(function(place) {
                        this.autocompletePlace = place;
                    })
                }.bind(this));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` or `this.$el.querySelector()`, though accessing arbitrary DOM elements is an indication that you might be approaching things wrong.

Comment: What would be a suitable approach then? I guess you talk about binding the element instead?

Comment: That ref should work. `ref` works on anything in the template of the component. Probably need to see more code to understand why it *doesn't* work. Possibly your `this` reference is incorrect?

Comment: Possibly `this` is not what you think it is, where you are using it.

Comment: I just added more code for clarification purposes. Hope this gives you more insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bound the outer function, but not the inner one. Try

```
this.initAutoCompleteListener(function(place) {
     this.autocompletePlace = place;
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: @sesc360 glad to help :)

Comment: nice one... :))

Answer (score 0):

You can access HTML tags the same way using $refs, find below example:

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <input
      type="text"
      id="searchAddress"
      name="searchAddress"
      class="form-control"
      ref="searchAddress"
      placeholder="Input placeholder"
      v-model="inputModel">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Hello from './components/Hello'

  export default {
    name: 'app',

    data() {
      return {
        inputModel: ''
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      const el = this.$refs.searchAddress
      console.log('Ref to input element: ', el)
      console.log('Placeholder attr from the ref element: ', el.placeholder) // logs "Input placeholder"
    }
  }
```